# Extend Windows Explorer Views like GAC View

Tags: windows, shell, explorer

Is it possible to extend Windows Explorer in Windows 7 with a custom view like "C:\windows\assembly". Behind this is a normal Folder Hierarchy (Visible via Cmd).

Are there any tools to spy into this microsoft implementation in order to find some possibilites?

EDIT:
Is there a documentation for HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no magic and no need to spy anything, it all works with COM natively in Windows, no reason to spy or sniff from the registry, just plenty of theory to learn...

most of the examples are provided in C / C++, read this article for an introduction, in there you find many interface names and other keywords you can use to refine your search:

**Edit:** thanks to Luke's comment...

[Understanding Shell Namespace Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144095%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This is definitely implemented as a [Shell Namespace Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144095%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), not a bar or band.

Comment: I've already checked the articles on the msdn. It is clear to me for toolbars and panes. But i struggle with the full content view.

Comment: the right keywords for google and you find anything. no is everything much more clear to me! thanks a lot guy's!